# How to extract string between two delimiters in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Currently I have string line  `feature/USRSTORY-447-testing-rest-api`

I want to extract only `USRSTORY-447`.

Currently I have a line written which works and I get the output below:

```
str.substring(str.indexOf("/") + 1, str.indexOf("-") + 4);

USRSTORY-447
```

But in future when the number count after `USRSTORY -` has more than 3 digits then it will only fetch the first 3 of those after ´-`   Can anyone help how to resolve this so that there is no need to change the above line of code every time?

Comment: What happens if you use str.indexOf("/") instead of 4?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**`StringGroovyMethods.find(regex)`**](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#find-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) to extract the part you are interested in expressed with regular expression:

```
def str = "feature/USRSTORY-447-testing-rest-api".find(/USRSTORY-\d+/)
assert str == 'USRSTORY-447'
```

It extracts `USRSTORY-447` from given string.

You can even generalize it a little bit - assuming that `USRSTORY` may be replaced by any uppercased string, following expression will handle this case:

```
"feature/USRSTORY-447-testing-rest-api".find(/([A-Z]+)-\d+/)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for extracting those informations with a regexp.  It's more flexible and you can get all the other things needed by name too.  E.g.

```
def s = 'feature/USRSTORY-447-testing-rest-api'

def matches = s =~ /(?<type>.*?)\/(?<ticketid>[A-Z]+-\d+?)-(?<desc>.*)/

if (matches) { 
    def result = ["type", "ticketid", "desc"].collectEntries{[it, matches.group(it)]}
    println result.inspect()
    // => ['type':'feature', 'ticketid':'USRSTORY-447', 'desc':'testing-rest-api']
}
```